# Move from a Raid 0 configuration to single drive: is possible to copy the OS?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, raid

I have a computer with 2x128GB M2 drives, which are mounted in Raid0 configuration. This is how the laptop was sold; so the main drive hold the recovery partition and the OS.

I want to upgrade the drive but I also want to avoid to re-install 200 GB of software, so I was planning to clone the disk on a larger one, and then swap the drives. Although I was told that

- I can't do that because if I clone the raid drives on a single drive, the machine won't boot when I put the single drive in
- I cannot use the raid0 drives, until I "break" the raid0 first; otherwise I won't be able to format them as single drives.

Is this accurate? and if so, how can I achieve my goal ? (copy Windows as is on the larger drive, making the disk bootable and being able to re-use the 2 128 GB drives as single drives)

Comment: It's not completely clear what your final configuration should be: 1 128BG + 1 bigger drive? 2 bigger drives? About what you can do, it's relevant to know what kind of RAID is currently in place: hardware or software?

Answer (score 0):

You have already cloned the data to a single drive, which is possible
since under RAID-0 the too disks appear basically as one disk.

You should have left unallocated space on the disk of about one gigabyte for
Windows to install its recovery and UEFI partitions.

To solve the problem of boot, all that is left is to repair Windows 10
from a boot USB.

You should try to do
[Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).
If this fails, start a full Windows 10 installation, but ensure that it finds
your existing installation so as to do an "upgrade" rather than install
a fresh instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did clone the original raid disk which included a 100 mb UEFI partition and a 1 GB recovery partition; on top of the C partition. Is this what you meant when you said "you should have left unallocated space on the disk for the recovery and UEFI partition"?

Comment: Yes, but you did better than I thought. I would still leave that unallocated gigabyte, in case Windows will for some reason not reuse the existing partitions.